# ANTLR Grammar for literal string with length prefix

Tags: c#, antlr, grammar, antlr3

How do I write following BNF Grammar in ANTLR?

```
literal = "{" number "}" CRLF *CHAR8
        ; Number represents the number of CHAR8s
```

For example `{6}\r\nLENGTH` should be mapped to `"LENGTH"` string.

Will following work?

```
literal: 
   | '{' ('0'..'9')+ '}\r\n'  
        {  
            // C# Code for Lexer
            Text = Text.Trim();
            int n = int.Parse(Text.Substring(1,Text.Length-2));
            Text = "";
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
               input.Consume();
            }            
        }
  ;
```

I am getting this working as a Lexer rule, but problem is I am getting mismatched token, I am not getting token as literal.

Comment: Would a solution that does this in 2 steps be ok? e.g. pass two checks that the number to the left and the string to the right are the same length.

Comment: I didnt get you, I dont know much about ANTLR and I just saw its generated C# and based on that I have written this, the problem is, it has few methods such as LeaveRule etc, I want to know what shall be my last statement? LeaveRule() should be called or not.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 why C# was removed from here? The target language for ANTLR grammar is C#

Comment: @BartKiers, sorry, typo, yes I corrected it to 6 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works correctly,

```
literal: 
   | '{' ('0'..'9')+ '}\r\n'  
        {  
            // C# Code for Lexer
            Text = Text.Trim();
            int n = int.Parse(Text.Substring(1,Text.Length-2));
            Text = "";
            for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
               Text += (char) input.LA(1);
               input.Consume();
            }            
        }
  ;
```

`Text += (char)input.LA(1);` was missing and for some reason, we have to count i from 0 to n+1.